# com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.androidhttp is deprecated

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

Hello I try to communicate with google drive api on android app, but I see this deprecated by google, how I solve this to my code?

```
    void fun(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount){
    Log.d("jjj","fun called");
    GoogleAccountCredential credential =
            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
    credential.setSelectedAccount(signInAccount.getAccount());
    Drive googleDriveService =
            new Drive.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new GsonFactory(),
                    credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Drive API Migration")
                    .build();
    editor.putBoolean("SyncOn",true).commit();
    mDriveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);
```

picture with problem:
[deprecated code picture - line problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0MPT.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `AndroidHttp`, use [`NetHttpTransport`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/blob/master/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/http/javanet/NetHttpTransport.java#L55) directly or switch to Cronet which is better supported.

```
Drive googleDriveService = new Drive.Builder(
        new NetHttpTransport(),
        new GsonFactory(),
        credential)
    .setApplicationName("Drive API Migration")
    .build();
```

Reference: https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/blob/master/google-http-client-android/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/extensions/android/http/AndroidHttp.java#L35